# How to convert JavaScript code to a xml representation of the ast?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-serialization, antlr

I am building an XML serializer of JavaScript Abstract Syntax Trees with ANTLR. 
The generator is quite complete but I would like to know if there are any conventions about some issues such as:

- how handle angle brackets in strings or regular expressions?
- how to translate if-then-else (e.g. will the else node be inside the if one or not)?

More generally: does such a translator already exist? Is there any existing XSD for this XML-based language?

### EDIT

I am currently interested in free tools only.

Comment: I don't understand "quite complete ... but how to handle if-then-else" in the same breath.  If you have the AST, exporting an XML version of it is pretty trivial: walk the AST, spit out node and children descriptors.    If you do that, your question about "how to handle if-then-else" vanishes, as you must have already solved it in building the AST.

Comment: You ask, "does such a translator exist?".  If the question is, "does this exist in ANTLR?" then I suspect you'll find the answer at the ANTLR.org site.   My company has exactly such a translator with all the issues resolved; if you'd like to see an output sample as an answer here I'll produce one for you specifically for JavaScript.  Here's a link to an XML output for Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376662/how-a-ast-for-an-object-oriented-programming-language-would-look-like/6378997#6378997

Comment: "Quite complete" = the translator actually produces XML code from JavaScript but I would like to know some state-of-the-art similar work to make a comparison about its quality. The if-then-else issue was just an example and my question stressed about _conventions_: should I translate it in <if><then></then><else></else></if> or in <if></if><then></then><else></else> or in <if><then/><else/></if>...

Comment: "Conventions"? The simplest conventions are best. Produce XML that matches the shape of the AST you have.  I'd expect an <ifthenelse> tag with 3 children.

Answer (score 0):

Parsers which perform code generation from XML and generate XML from code are readily available:

- [Custom PMD Rules - O'Reilly Media](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/09/pmd_rules.html)
- [estools/esvalid: confirm that a SpiderMonkey format AST represents an ECMAScript program](https://github.com/estools/esvalid)
- [jantimon/handlebars-to-ecmascript: Convert handlebars to an ecmascript AST](https://github.com/jantimon/handlebars-to-ecmascript)
- [estools/estemplate: Proper (AST-based) JavaScript code templating with source maps support.](https://github.com/estools/estemplate)
- [estools/esrecurse: AST recursive visitor](https://github.com/estools/esrecurse)
- [estools/estraverse: ECMAScript JS AST traversal functions](https://github.com/estools/estraverse)
- [estools/escope: Escope: ECMAScript scope analyzer](https://github.com/estools/escope)
- [estools/esquery: ECMAScript AST query library.](https://github.com/estools/esquery)

> You ask, "does such a translator exist?". If the question is, "does this exist in ANTLR?" then I suspect you'll find the answer at the ANTLR.org site. My company has exactly such a translator with all the issues resolved; if you'd like to see an output sample as an answer here I'll produce one for you specifically for JavaScript.
>
> Here's a link to an XML output for Java: [What would an AST (abstract syntax tree) for an object-oriented programming language look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376662/how-a-ast-for-an-object-oriented-programming-language-would-look-like/6378997#6378997)

**References**

- [Parsers, Part IV: A Java Cross-Reference Tool (pdf)](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/sandbox/trunk/jxr/maven-jxr/maven-jxr-java/src/site/resources/SeriesPt4.pdf)
- [o:XML Development Tool Chain](http://www.o-xml.org/documentation/o-xml-tool-chain.html)
- [Command line rendering | Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside)
- [Parser API - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API)