# Parse tree representation using JavaCC

Tags: java, xml, parsing, tree, javacc

I built a parser in JavaCC that given for example:   let a : int =5+4;
it displays:

```
Start
 Sxl
  Statement
   VariableDecl
    Identifier
    Type
    Expression
     SimpleExpression
      Term
       Factor
        Literal
         IntegerLiteral
      AdditiveOp
      Term
       Factor
        Literal
         IntegerLiteral
 Parsed.
```

that works fine however I need enhance this parser to output to an xml file and output the following output for the above input:

```
letNode( Identier(X), ExprNode( PlusNode( IntegerLiteral(8), IntegerLiteral(2) )))
```

How can this be done, do I need to use normal Java or there is some functionality in JavaCC?

Comment: JavaCC won't do this for you.  You'll have to walk over the AST and spit out the XML yourself.  You can see a similar result with another tool at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7882118/120163  [I note that the output you exhibit isn't XML].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are using JJT.  Here are 3 ways to convert the input file to an XML file using JavaCC or JJT.

1. It is easy to edit the generated `SimpleNode` class so that it outputs XML -- or whatever format you want.
2. An alternative is to use JavaCC rather than JJT and to make SAX calls so that your parser constructs an XML document.  Then it is easy to output the XML document.
3. A third option is to stick with JJT and modify the `SimpleNode` class to produce an XML document (using either SAX or DOM). Then the XML document can outputted.

Comment: Is option 1 and 3 different?

Comment: I can't use this format for example? void Identifier() #MyID :

Comment: @IraBaxter What I meant by (1) was that he/she could directly produce a string or print to a file. What I meant by (2) and (3) was that he/she could first produce an XML object and then use standard methods to output that to a file.

Comment: @user3599420 I think you are asking whether you can use JJT. If so, yes. Options (1) and (3) use JJT. Only option (2) avoids JJT.

Comment: I started working on that thanks! please see my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457951/javacc-dump-method-to-print-ast