# JavaCC dump method to print AST

Tags: dump, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

I am using JavaCC to print an AST in a particular format.
I need it to be like this :

```
LetNode( Identier(X), ExprNode( PlusNode( IntegerLiteral(8), IntegerLiteral(2) )))
```

but  I am getting:

```
Start(LetNode(Identifier(x)(ExprNode(IntegerLiteral(5)(PlusNode(IntegerLiteral(5)()))
```

I am using the dump method to print this:

```
public void dump(String prefix) {
  System.out.print(toString(prefix));
  System.out.print("(");
  if (children != null) {

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
      SimpleNode n = (SimpleNode)children[i];
      if (n != null) {
        n.dump(prefix +"");
      }
    }
    System.out.print(")");
  }
}
```

}

The output without any modification is :

```
Start
  Sxl
   Statement
    VariableDecl
     Identifier
     Type
     Expression
      SimpleExpression
       Term
        Factor
         Literal
          IntegerLiteral
       AdditiveOp
       Term
        Factor
         Literal
          IntegerLiteral
```

My method:

```
void AdditiveOp():
{}  
{
   (Plus() /*#Add(2)*/ | Minus() | Or())

}

void Plus():
{
}
{
  (< PLUS >)
  #PlusNode
}
```

If I remove the /* */ it does not work as it says it expects something else not +

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First you'll want to change the way the tree is produced.  Currently you have essentially the parse tree. What you'll want is more of a abstract syntax tree. Read the documentation for JJT to find out how to do this.

Comment: I did and I modified the method dump() infact I got some output as I said above. All I need is to get the Plus Node before both the integers not in the middle but I can't figure out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to make an AST with JJT for an expression grammar is to do something like this

```
void AdditiveExpression() #void :
{ Token t ; }
{
  MultiplicativeExpression()
  (  "+"  MultiplicativeExpression()  #Add(2)
  |  "-"  MultiplicativeExpression()  #Subtract(2)   
  )*
}
```

Comment: Regarding the "(2)", you must read the JJT documentation. In short `#Add(2)` means: (a) pop two nodes from the stack, (b) make a new node of type `Add`, (c) add those two nodes as children to the new node, (d) push the new node on the stack. Thus the whole method pushes 1 node on the stack, assuming the same is true of `MultiplicativeExpression`.