# JavaCC AST representation

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

I am using JavaCC to generate a parser and one method is to accept 4 + 5 for example which works well.

However now I need to modify this so that it prints PlusNode(IntegerLiteral(4) , IntegerLiteral(5))

I modified some code for this however it is printing :

```
(ExprNode(IntegerLiteral(4),PlusNode,IntegerLiteral(5),),)
```

since the rule is

```
INTLITERAL PLUS INTLITERAL
```

My dump method in SimpleNode is:

```
public void dump(String prefix) {
  System.out.print(toString(prefix));

  if (children != null) {
        System.out.print("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
      SimpleNode n = (SimpleNode)children[i];
      if (n != null) {
        n.dump(prefix +"");
      }System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.print(")");
  }
}
```

How can  I get the plus before and remove the ,,, in the last part?

Comment: This is the third question that's asking the same thing from the same poster. It is better to edit your earlier questions to improve them than to ask the same question again and again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaCC dump method to print AST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457951/javacc-dump-method-to-print-ast)