# Java - Parsing XML file from Eclipse AST view

Tags: java, xml-parsing, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

How can I get the XML file of the Abstract syntax tree in Eclipse on Mac OS? I tried to find this file but were not success

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Save the AST of a given Java file (`.java` or `.class`?) as XML?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want to save the AST of a given .java file as XML.

Comment: As far as I know, Eclipse didn't have this feature built-in, nor do I know a plug-in that can do that. Without Eclipse, your question is a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7881668/6505250).

Comment: Yes, I already read this question. I want to save xml from eclipse because I have an eclipse AST View, which presents full of the code's components.

Comment: There is no "XML file of the Abstract syntax tree" to save. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, I used ASTExtractor to solve my problem. It worked. Thank you, guys :D