# Parsing Java source code with C++

Tags: java, c++, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, semantic-analysis

I would like to create an Java source code [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Overview_of_process) functionality in C++. The purpose of this application is to generate a [syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) into the internal data structure so that I am able to walk the data tree structure and analyse it on my own.

Which tools could help me to achive my goal?

Comment: There are many tools for this. Google for parser generators.

Comment: The obvious question would be why do you want to do this? You may find it simpler and easier to run `javac` and parse the byte code generated instead.

Comment: Doing things like these helps tremendously in understanding the basic principles of the material you're working on. E.G. I once wrote a full SGML parser, and that helped me answer a lot of questions that I didn't even knew I had.

Comment: @MarceloCantos So, at first I need to pick up a parser generator? OK. I found Bison and YACC softwares. How about one of these?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: At the moment I am doing some preliminary research about how could I break the language structure into peaces. This way I am able to understand the Java language better - I think :-).

Comment: If you just want to look at a real Java parse tree, you can see a small one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378997/120163

Comment: @melter: "Break the langauge into pieces"?  I thought that was what the grammar did, in effect.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) could help you, but understanding a Java program requires to load the relevant classes referenced in that program.

Comment: Moreover, they may be existing grammars for C++.

Comment: @Agemen: I found out that ANTLR is able to generate C++ source code but I have determined that I am not going to use any language that is using virtual machine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/) with [this grammar](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs118/notation/java11.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try;

http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/Coco/

It has different ports like C#, Java, C++, F#, VB.Net, Oberon etc. and it has a nice language scanner & parser for different langauges. So, you can use it for parsing java from c++.