# What standalone Java parsers are available?

Tags: java, parsing, netbeans, intellij-idea, metaprogramming

I need a standalone Java parser (program which "reads" .java source files and generates AST [ie objects representing the contents of source]).

- There's https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/ but it supports only Java 1.5
- I know how to run Eclipse Java parser in "standalone" mode, but this parser uses too many Eclipse JARs, is too complex, and uses EPL license, which is GPL-incompatible
- other IDEs (IntelliJ, NetBeans, JDeveloper) and javac compiler also must have some Java parsers, but I can't find any documentation how to use them in "standalone" applications

Any help? Maybe somebody of You also tried to do some standalone Java parsing?

Comment: ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has a [full Java 1.7 parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378997/120163).  But a parser isn't enough, if you intend to anything serious; check out Life After Parsing.  DMS has the support you need beyond that to process Java interestingly, such as , attribute grammars, symbol tables, transformation rules, etc, plus good documentation for all of that.  DMS is designed to support the construction of custom langauge analysis tools.  It isn't GPL-compatible, though.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaCC](http://java.net/projects/javacc) has a Java 1.5 grammar.