# In the Java Abstract Syntax Tree, how is System.out.println("shadoobee") represented?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I can't find basic practical examples anywhere online about `AST`s represent real code.

Can anyone tell me how `System.out.println("shadoobee")` is represented in the tree? What elements are used (i.e. `System.out` appears to be a `QualifiedName`, I'm assuming) and how they are arranged in the tree?

Comment: Whose grammar are you using?

Comment: Which parser or library are you using ?

Comment: I'd expect it have a root node called statment, child node method-call, with method-call left-child being path containing a.b.c.d, and right child containing arguments.  You can see a real parse for Java code (not your specific example) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378997/120163