# Can I get an XML AST of C/C++/Java code without compiling it?

Tags: java, c++, c, xml, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to create an XML file with AST representation of source code, but **without compiling it**. I didn't find any sufficient solution so far. Here is what I tried:

- Using XML printer in clang - `clang -cc1 -ast-print-xml` - it would be nice, but it was [removed from clang](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=127141)
- [srcML](http://www.sdml.info/projects/srcml/) toolkit, which in theory works well, but has poor parser (for Java it's not even fully 1.5-compatible)

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Clang won't handle Java, AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, the "XML" that  *was*  printed by Clang,  wasn't really XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Java, see [What would an AST (abstract syntax tree) for an object-oriented programming language look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376662/how-a-ast-for-an-object-oriented-programming-language-would-look-like/6378997#6378997)

For C, see [get human readable AST from c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388771/get-human-readable-ast-from-c-code/17393852#17393852)

Both of these are produced by one engine: our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.   DMS also has a full C++11 parser that can produce similar XML. (EDIT Jan 2016: now full C++ 14 for GCC and Visual C++).

I don't think XML is really a good idea: it is enormous and klunky, and the analysis tools you can bring to bear on it are ... what?  XSLT: That's not very useful for analyzing programs.   Read the XML into a DOM and climb over that?  You'll find that you are missing lots of useful support (symbol tables, etc.); AST's are just not enough.  See my essay on *Life After Parsing* (check my bio or google).

You are better off using a set of integrated machinery that provides all kinds of *consistent* support for analyzing (multiple) programming languages (using the ASTs as a foundation).  This is what DMS is designed to do.

Comment: Heh, I felt that you will write an answer. I saw your answers in related questions already. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: You asked if there were any alternatives.   I'd be happy for other people to point out DMS, but they don't.