# Is there a way to see the result(output) of lexical and syntax analysis of a java program compilation process?

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

Want to know if there is a way to see the output of java lexical and analysis phase while compiling a java program. We can see the byte code(Virtual machine code) using javap. Is there a way to see the output of Lexical and Analysis Phase? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to find a tool that generates an abstract syntax tree. But why do you need this?

Comment: I am reading a textbook and there is a question "Show the token classes, or “words”, put out by the lexical analysis phase corresponding
to this Java source input: sum = sum + unit ∗ /∗ accumulate sum ∗/ 1.2e-12 ;". The theoretical solution is there in the book, wanted to know if there was any way to find the answer practically.

Comment: It's a lot more work to do it programmatically than to trace back knowing the rules of operator precedence and assocativity.

Comment: Getting a real parser right is hard.  You want to use a tool that has been through trial-by-fire.   For a tool and an example of what Java parsing looks like, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376662/would-would-an-ast-abstract-syntax-tree-for-an-object-oriented-programming-lan/6378997#6378997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to analysis the `abstract syntax tree` of the java source file. There are some samples:

- https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html#accessing-the-abstract-syntax-tree-the-compiler-tree-api
- http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Erni08b.pdf

You can debug the first example and you will find the source java file will be loaded into a `Trees` object.