# building an AST with antlr4 for the java language

Tags: parsing, tree, abstract-syntax-tree, antlr4

I am trying to construct an AST using the latest version of ANTLR (v4), i found a couple of links here in stack-overflow and also on the net, that shows you how to do it for a simple grammars. However, i wanted an AST for the Java.g4 grammar (Java language). Currently , i was following the approached recommended here (https://codevomit.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/antlr4-project-with-maven-tutorial-episode-3/). However based on this approach, i needed to label all the production rules that have alternatives.

Hence, i would greatly appreciate it if someone informed me if there is a different alternative for building an AST using ANTLR4 or if there is an already labeled java.g4 grammar.

Comment: You can use this grammar for java https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4 . There is also a grammar for java8 https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8

Comment: @VincentAranega Thanks. However,I am  already playing with those grammars.  What i need is a **labeled grammar** for the alternative production rules so that I can have different visitor methods for the different labels when antlr4 generates JavaVisitor.java. This will allow me to have the abstraction that I want.

Comment: ANTLR4 will build a parse tree for you, which is pretty convenient; it takes effort to build a real AST, and it may not pay off as much as you hope in terms of effort.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1916687/120163

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks. Is there a more convenient way to build an AST for a *function body* (an AST representation of a method) other than employing ANTLR4.

Comment: @user1577269: You seem to have 3 questions:  a) can you use ANTLR4 to parse *just* function bodies, b) is there a convenient way to build ASTs with ANTLR4, and c) is there a way to do this other than ANTLR4. Regarding a), you could bend the grammar by making the goal rule also allow a "function" (presumably you mean method).  b) AFAIK, no, but I've already responded to this in previous comment.  c) If you want to get *AST*s, the ONLY convenient answer I know is our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit, and yes, you can ask it to parse just a method.  I'll elaborate in an answer if you ask me to.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378997/120163 for "ast" vs "cst" examples

Comment: I have created a sample project creating AST for Java using Antlr v4 https://github.com/adamsiemion/antlr-java-ast

Answer (score 1):

All of the subrule alternates do not need to be labeled.  Label just those alternates where generation of a discrete context object is desired.  Really just the `statement`, `expression`, and (maybe) `primary` rules warrant labeling.

Labeling itself is [trivial](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels).

Comment: For OP's specific problem, he probably wants to label the (partial) rule for method declarations.  Then apparantly ANTLR can be launched to parse "just" that rule/label. (I only know what I read; I haven't actually done this).

Comment: Labeling link is not accesible anonymously (requests contacting admin at theantlrguy.atlassian.net)